# any issues in this controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

when i use routers without controllers then my routers are working fine but when i add controllers in it. then my routers stop working... can anyone please tell me about my issues in routers functions?

**LOGIN CONTROLLER:**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {


  $scope.login = function() {
    console.log("LOGIN user: " + $scope.username + " - PW: " + $scope.password);

    LoginService.loginUser($scope.username, $scope.password).success(function(data) {
      console.log("Login Successful");
        $state.go('home');
    }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        })
    })
  }

});
```

**ROUTERS CODE**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'page2.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
             .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'index.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });
```

Comment: Stop working? Any errors given in console?

Comment: if i use controllers then the url is like this "http://localhost:8100/?"

Comment: if i don't then it's like this " http://localhost:8100/?restart=769171#/login"

Comment: We need your console logs of the errors !

Comment: i don't know about console log.. can you please explain ?

Comment: @AzharCh in your browser press f12 to open developer tools, then go to console and see if there are errors

Comment: okay thanyou for your help

Comment: i just posted my console .... can you please help now

Comment: for Gods sake, dont you see any posted answer?

Comment: opx my bad... and thnkyou for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

and

```
angular.module('starter')
```

are two entirely different concept . While `[]` converts the the method to a setter method. Meaning It will create a new instance of starter module. But if you do not use the third bracket it becomes a getter method meaning it will return already declared module.

Thats why you need to use

```
angular.module('starter').controller('', function(){});
```

for details look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Answer (score 3):

Your controller is wrongly declared. Remove injector from your module while creating controller. Something like

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
   //...
});
```

Because of these reasons, it is best to have your module created in separate file. So you would have

**module.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

**config.js**

```
angular.module('starter').config(function(){});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter').controller('', function(){});
```

Comment: Not necessary if this is indeed the module's creation

Comment: you cannot have same module created twice

Comment: Damn I didn't look right, you are correct he declares his module twice

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic']) ,
```

this code create an instance of angular app named **starter**.  you should create an instance of an app only once. but you created twice here.

only use

```
angular.module('starter')
```

to use the app while declaring controller or config .   but you should be careful that first create instance then use it. 
that means

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

should use in the portion which will execute first .